# PHP & AJAX Sessions : Session variables different on AJAX page than on page called from

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a login page than involved destroying a session and starting a new one. I have very inconsistent results between both Chrome and Firefox.

I am clearing the session using:

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
```

But variables in the session seem to still exist until I refresh the page and then they disappear. My second problem ontop of this is that crucial $_SESSION variables are different on ajax pages called from this login page. This is causing big problems and inconsistent results on ajax pages.

**What is the best way to destroy a session and set it with fresh variables that will be available to ajax pages?**

Comment: Could you provide some further code to see where you're destroying the session, and how/where you're calling the session variables that are not disappearing? Can you also give an example of your AJAX call?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using session cookies you have to "remove" them as well.

```
$cookie_params = session_get_cookie_params();

setcookie(
    session_name(),
    false,
    strtotime('2000-01-01')
    $cookie_params['path'],
    $cookie_params['domain'],
    $cookie_params['secure']
);
```

Of course the cookie will not be deleted by the browser until you sent the response.
The new session would be created on the next request.

PS: The manual states:

> Only use `session_unset()` for older deprecated code that does not use `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1):

I found:

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
```

To be very unpredictable and yielded varying results between browsers which is unusual for PHP.

**To resolve I simply replaced it with:**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
```

I know this doesn't completely clear and replace a session, but all I really needed was the session to be cleared. The fact that the session has the same session_id doesn't really matter in my scenario.

Hope this helps some people having the same mare as me!